# JQuery Form Not Submitting At All

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a form and a script like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("ready");

  $("#find_stuff").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Meme</title>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>


  <!-- This is temp, we will put in another file later !-->

  <form id="find_stuff">
    <p>Thing I want</p><br>
    <input type="text" name="things_needed">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

keep in mind that when I go to the website, I do see the ready alert, but when I click submit on the form, it dosent do anything.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce, I see the alert when I click submit

Comment: add method="POST" and action="/your_action" in form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this works for me.  but, um...  I didnt change much.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("ready");

    $( "#find_stuff" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Meme</title>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>


<form id="find_stuff">
    <p>Thing I want</p><br>
    <input type="text" name="things_needed">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect it was because I was rude to someone else's answer when they said you should add an action to your form element.  who knows though.  heh, good luck, have fun!  @RobertWestbury

Comment: Didn't downvote, but this doesn't change anything from the original code, it just adds it into a snippet.

Comment: @chrisz strangely enough, that is mostly true.  I threw it in a snippet to debug it, and when I removed the `script` tag from the body, it was working.  I did mention that in the answer.

Comment: It works even with the script tag in the body, check the updated question

Comment: @chrisz yeh I dont know why it wouldnt have worked originally.  ...  that is why I put it in a snippet to see.  (the original question was not in snippet)